# apache wont follow symlinks | 403 permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and have a problem with the Apache configuration:

I created a Symlink from `/var/www/html` torwards `/home/me/myWebDirectory`

but `localhost/myWebDirectory` renders a

> 403-permission denied

and in fact, `sudo -u www-data ls /home/me/myWebDirectory` returns a permission denied too

apache2.conf had following directive :

```
<Directory /var/www>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

I changed it for `<Directory /var/www/html>`, but no result.

I tried to add the `me` user to `www-data group` with this command `sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName`, but that didn't help either

what is it that I missed?

**EDIT**:
I changed the group of `/home/me/myWebDirectory` into www-data with rx rights, but no success either...

As I said, I was well aware that I had a reading permission problem as this `sudo -u www-data ls /home/me/myWebDirectory` returning me a permission denied too (which means www-data doesn't have the rights to see what in it).

But I need certain point of your answer to be clearer :

> Also you should use url "localhost/html" instead of "localhost/myWebDirectory".

Actually I've made the Symlink like follow :

- `cd /var/www/html`
- `ln -s /home/user/me/myWebDirectory myWebDirectory`

so I think accessing `localhost/myWebDirectory` is the right address, no?

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

- since ubuntu 14.04, Apache DocRoot is `/var/www/html`, **why should i chhange its owner** (like many other deamons, roots by default).
- `/localhost/testfile.html` works fine (undertsand testfile is in `/var/www/html`)
- `/localhost/phpmyadmin` works too, even if it's a SymLink to `/usr/share` (while m trying to have a symLink to `/home/user`...)

> chmod +r /var/www/html  # add read permission to dir

```
chmod +r /var/www/html/* # add read permission to files in dir
```

- Add read permission to who? to myUser?
- But that is exactly what I don't want to do.
- I actually want apache to be able to read in /home/me/myWebDirectory and not myUser to go write in apache's directories.

**NB:**
I know there's another way to do it, while activating the apache `mod_userdir` and that's probably what i'll be going to do next.
But first i'd like to understand how to make this "simple" solution work...

Answer (score 1):

i finally solved my problem with following solution, may it help anyone in the future...

> sudo chown me:www-data /home/me
> sudo chmod 710 /home/me
>
> sudo chown -R me:www-data /home/me/myWebDirectory
>
> sudo chmod -R g+r /home/me/myWebDirectory

Caution : you may for example not want all subdirectories to be readable by apache, so adapt the -R(ecursive) directive.

But important is to give the apache user group read access to ur home then read access to the concerned infant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because of missing read permissions.
Execute:

```
# chmod +r /var/www/html  # add read permission to dir
# chmod +r /var/www/html/* # add read persmission to files in dir
# chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Also your shouse use url "localhost/html" instead of "localhost/myWebDirectory".